# pwa support for READ_PHONE_NUMBERS in Android 11

Tags: progressive-web-apps

Does pwa support for READ_PHONE_NUMBERS in Android 11.

I have dual SIM, can it show available mobile numbers on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the [Contacts API](https://web.dev/contact-picker/). I don't know if it handles dual SIMs. Here's [another resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Contact_Picker_API).